# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '21,7'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm just starting learn python, and I try to do a model in machine learning, and I have a probleme with column in my data.
the first problem is: In my data, I have the variable "IMC" with data such as 11,3 and I should convert it to 11.3 how can I do this please?

The second problem is: I have `"GENDER": MALE, FEMALE.` and I encode it like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
number = LabelEncoder()
export_data['SEXE'] = number.fit_transform(export_data['SEXE'].astype(float))
```

and the probleme is when i encode my output (y), it's a dtype: object to float like I do with gender, i have problem when I want to unencode it ...

Comment: Regarding your first problem: You can simply use pandas' [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method. For example: `df["IMC"] = df["IMC"].replace(',', '.')`. Can you elaborate the second issue again? I don't get the problem.

Comment: I tried this, but still don't work...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to use a regex instead of simply using the dot, i.e. `df["IMC"] = df["IMC"].replace(',', '.', regex=True)`

Comment: @Gusto I don't think regex would work, "." is a special character -> .replace(',', '.', regex=False) would be better (didn't check the whole code, though...)

Comment: df["IMC"] = df["IMC"].str.replace(',', '.', regex=False).astype(float) would be my choice

Comment: I kind of agree. But I double checked it with some code and it turned out that setting `regex=True` actually helped (with `regex=False` it doesn't work. At least without the `.str`). Most surprising, I though that with regex=True it has to be `df["IMC"] = df["IMC"]..replace(',', '\.', regex=True)`.